# Use Craft globals for CSS styles

Tags: templating, craft3, globals, css

Is it possible to pass a value from Craft global setting into a CSS/SCSS file? So for example I want to be able to allow the end user to customise colours and fonts without having to include it inline.

Has anyone achieved this or similar?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s possible to do this by making the entire CSS file a Twig template.

Create a new file in your `templates` folder, such as `templates/css/styles.css`, with all the dynamic styles you want.

To prevent the browser from reloading the file on each request, make sure you set cache headers in the template.

```
{# Tell the browser to cache this page for 30 days #}
{% set expiry = now|date_modify('+30 days') %}

{% header "Cache-Control: max-age=" ~ (expiry.timestamp - now.timestamp) %}
{% header "Pragma: cache" %}
{% header "Expires: " ~ expiry|date('D, d M Y H:i:s', 'GMT') ~ " GMT" %}
```

Then load the CSS file just like any other from your webpage templates.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Comment: Thats awesome thank you! I'm guessing you could adapt to possibly handle scss?

Comment: @Chrisl2310 not natively but maybe possible with this plugin: https://plugins.craftcms.com/scss